# Putting same values in an array

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction. I have an array that contains numbers, some of them are the same. I would like to make a new array that has all the same numbers in an array inside the new array. Not sure I explained that right, find it hard typing with this new phone as well. Using JavaScript btw should of added that first.

const array = [1,1,1,2,10,25,10]

I want

const new Array = [[1,1,1],2,[10,10],25]

Not really looking for answer just to be guided in right direction, thank you for your time.

Comment: What should be the order of that new array? You most likely want to do that with `Array::reduce` and use a `Map` or an object as an accumulator for the grouping and the use `Array::map` to convert the `Map`/object back to an array.

Comment: you can add same values with different indexes

Comment: If you want a hardcoded solution, loop all the indexes and get all same value and put it on an array then create a new array to put the results. Use bubble loop method to loop all the way to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = [1,1,1,2,10,25,10];
const groupedNumbersMap = array.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if (!(num in acc)) acc[num] = num;
  else {
    const value = acc[num];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) value.push(num);
    else acc[num] = [num, num];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
const groupedNumbers = Object.keys(groupedNumbersMap).map(k => groupedNumbersMap[k]);

console.log(groupedNumbers);
```

Or with a `Map`:

```js
const array = [1,1,1,2,10,25,10];
const groupedNumbers = Array.from(array.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if (!acc.has(num)) acc.set(num, num);
  else {
    const value = acc.get(num);
    if (Array.isArray(value)) value.push(num);
    else acc.set(num, [num, num]);
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(groupedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
const array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 25, 10];
array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
const newList = array.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
    if (idx === 0) {
        return [[item]];
    } else {
        return acc.reduce((icc, a, i) => {
            if(acc.flat().includes(item)) {
                if(a.includes(item)) {
                    return [...icc, [...a, item]];
                }   
                return [...icc, a];
            } else {
                return [...acc, [item]]
            }

        }, [])
    }
}, [])
console.log(newList);
```